# Who is doing the thinking?

Tags: grammar, volitional-form

Observe the change:

> 彼女は行かないと思う。 "**I think** that she will not go"
>
> 彼女は行くまいと思う。 "**She thinks** that she will not go"

`彼女は` and `と思う` are conserved in the sentence, yet the person who is doing the thinking is different.

**(Question 1)** Is the use of the negative volitional form the direct cause of the change?

**(Question 2)** How do I make specific the person who is doing the thinking in each case?
 I.e. How do I express "I think that she will not go" using 行くまい and "She thinks that she will not go" using 行かない?

Comment: "yet the subject is different" says who?  I see a nuance, but not a change of subject.

Comment: @Axioplase perhaps "subject" was the wrong word to use. What I meant was that "the person who is doing the thinking" has changed.

Comment: In both sentences, the subject of 思う can be either the speaker or 彼女, although it is often clear from the context.

Comment: I don't know if it's a firm rule or not, but the Kanzen Master JLPT 2kyuu grammar book says that the subject of `～まい` is `私`, and that in third person scenarios you use `～まいと思っているらしい`/`～まいと思っているようだ` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (Question 2) How do I make specific the person who is doing the thinking in each case?
>   I.e. How do I express "I think that she will not go" using 行くまい and "She thinks that she will not go" using 行かない?

彼女が行くまいと(私は)思います。

and

彼女は行かないと思っている。

Comment: For 彼女は行かないと思っている, can't it also mean "I think(and am in a continued state of thinking that) she will not go"? How do I unambiguously state that she is the one doing the thinking and not anyone else?

Comment: @Flaw: I believe that in most cases, you wouldn't say "思っている" to express your opinion out of the box, and that it implies a change of subject.  It's more usage than grammar, and is a real pain for learners of Japanese.
As usual, it's a contextual issue…