# How do you say "the audio says..."

Tags: words, phrase-requests

Because I suspect 音声は〇〇と言う is wrong.

Comment: To elaborate further, I often ask things in Japanese on HelloTalk, but when it comes to inquire about what an audio file says, I don't know the natural way of saying it. Obviously I already asked there but no luck so far

Comment: Could you specify what kind of audio it is? Is it a textbook dialogue perhaps, or a piece of music that contains singing? Generally, if there's a more specific way to describe it you should probably go with that.

Answer (score 4):

First, 言う/言います usually sounds like it's about something habitual or something in the future. In this case, you have to use the progressive form and say 言っている or 言っています (see [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6538/5010)).

Most of the time, you can simply omit the subject and say 〇〇と言っています. Alternatively, you can change the subject and say ～さんは〇〇と言っています (if you know the speaker) or この人は〇〇と言っています (if you don't know who is speaking).

If you want to use 音声:

- この音声は〇〇と言っています: This is not wrong, but it sounds like the focus is the deciphering/transcribing (e.g., of a noisy audio, a foreign language, a single word) rather than the message itself.
- この音声によれば、〇〇と言っています: This is natural if the message in the audio is important (e.g., an anonymous political propaganda). ～によれば means "according to ～".

Comment: how about using 録音? How does it compare with 音声?

Comment: @Flaw In many cases they can be used interchangeably, but 音声 does not have to be a recorded one, and 録音 does not have to be a vocal or music. You can say 録音された音声, too.