# How to use wa and ga in sentence with two potential subjects, wa and ga help

Tags: particles

Please let me know if this sentence is correct as is; still learning.
金髪さんは私が彼女の友達だと思います

金髪さん could be both the topic or the subject; I'm confused in using both は and が in a sentence with two nouns mostly. I used は since its 金髪さん thoughts, and 私が because this is info i am conveying.

が marks the subject of a verb showing whats performing the action; and 金髪さん is the one performing the action of thinking. The sentence could be written 金髪さんが, depending on the context you could also be introducing new info, which would also be が. If that's the case what Particle would be used with 私. I'm Assuming が cant be used on both.
金髪さんが私_

Thanks,
Clarifying 彼女 as she.

Comment: What are you trying to say, in English? What's the previous context? This is a "correct" sentence, but probably does not mean what you're thinking. And are you certain with the word choice 金髪さん? It's not really a respectful way of referring to a person (sounds like "Mr. Blond").

Comment: Blondie san, how i saw it in  translated in Fairy tale. 
The whole sentence, "Blondie thinks i am her friend".

Answer (score 1):

At least, you need to change 思います to 思っています. 金髪さんは思います means "Blondie-san **will** think (in the future)". See: [思っている/言っている with a third person subject?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6538/5010)

> 金髪さんは私が彼女の友達だと**思っています**。

The content of と can be a complete sentence, so you can also use another は and say:

> 金髪さんは私**は**彼女の友達だと思っています。

You can also use [the AをB(だ)と思う pattern](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/55169/5010) and say:

> 金髪さんは私**を**彼女の友達(だ)と思っています。

<sub>(Note that 金髪さん is not really a respectful way of referring to a person. It may be acceptable in a fairy tale, but should be avoided in the modern social life.)</sub>

Comment: Context wise, for clarification i was going for Blondie thinks i am her friend, in the sense she already believes we are friends. Really i was just writing a sentence that forces the speaker to use Wa and Ga, i don't think 私は works because i is not the topic, blondes thoughts are. But could it be written 金髪さんが私は or if i use 金髪さんが what particle would i use with 私 to be grammatically correct?

Comment: @user3538292 Oh, so 金髪さん and 彼女 are the same person? Then you probably want to just say 金髪さんは私を友達だと思っています. Eight or nine times out of ten, the particle that comes after 金髪さん should be は, but depending on the context, が is more appropriate. It is basically very difficult to make a sentence where only one of が and は is correct regardless of the context.

Comment: Also just curious why 私を彼女? only way iv ever seen を is with verbs mostly, which is why that form is weird, since 思っています does not directly effect the noun.
For example, ケーキを食べる

Comment: @user3538292 [I posted a link for that](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/55169/5010).